# Influxdb2 influx grafana word cloud from multiple results

Tags: grafana, flux, word-cloud, influxdb-2

I am getting into influxdb2 and flux currently. My playground is, to scrape a public website and be able to visualize the words on the website in a word cloud in Grafana. This works, but when my range selection in Grafana results in multiple results, The words show up twice or more times - depending on the number of results.

My current flux query

```
  from(bucket: v.bucket)
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "wordcount" )
    |> group(columns: ["items"])
    |> sort(columns: ["_value"], desc: true)
```

My goal would be to combine all resulting rows into one result that holds the average occurrence of the words in the selected range. Example rows `fields` value:

```
{"field1": 2, "field2": 1, "field3": 4}
{"field1": 2, "field2": 1, "field4": 0}
```

Wanted result:

```
{"field1": 4, "field2": 2, "field3": 4, "field4": 0}
```

How would that be done?

Comment: Doesn't flux have something like `sum()` for this cases?

Comment: The problem was a bit more complex though, but I  figured it out. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the [Grafana forum](https://community.grafana.com/t/dynamically-adjust-values-to-currently-selected-range/75041/7), I was able to piece together a working solution for the problem. The complete query now looks as follows.

```
timestart = uint(v: v.timeRangeStart)
timestop = uint(v: v.timeRangeStop)
duration = duration(v:timestop - timestart)

from(bucket: v.bucket)
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "wordcount" )
  |> aggregateWindow(every: duration, fn: sum)
  |> group(columns: ["_time","_measurement"])
  |> sort(columns: ["_value"], desc: true)
```